# Different upload speed on youtube in different browsers

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, youtube, opera

So I upload a lot of heavy videos on youtube and upload speed is kinda important for me. My speed is 100 mbits and upload supposed to be 80 to nearby places. Speedtest to san jose shows 22 mbit upload speed, speedtest to frankfurt - 80 mbit upload speed.

Youtube is far away (across ocean) so 27 mbit that I got in chrome like a month ago was pretty ok and enough. But suddenly it dropped to 4-5 mbits.

I've been able to get highest upload speed in latest version of chrome, and only in chrome. Mozilla usually caps at 7 mbits (I heard it can only upload file in single thread while chrome can do multi threads), opera at 4, ie at 6-7. However, speed can vary for an unknown reason. You can suggest that this is an ISP thing, but why speed is different in different browsers?

Recently I started upload a video as usual in chrome, and what I got is 2 mbit. Reason for that was an outdated version of it, after a while I ran out of ideas an decided to update it - boom, speed is back.

Today I have 4-5 mbit in chrome for no reason. Tried firefox - 10-12 mbit (currently using it for uploading), ie - ~4.2, opera - ~4.5.

What is the reason for this speed differences between browsers and how do I hit the limit?

I tried some spooky youtube uploader thing which supposed to have multi thread uploading, it cant go higher than 7 mbit.

Tried copying files on ssd - no change.

My OS is win7x64sp1

Tried different ISP (30 mbit), different network card. Speed stays the same. Seems like problem is in my PC somewhere, but where?

Also tried uploading through API. Tried C# and python, 1.5 mbit speed in both

Sadly I don't have 2nd pc or notebook to test speed there.

Freed up some space from HDD I'm uploading from, now it has 400 GB free space and total 1.76 TB size (it had about 100 GB before). Speed hasn't changed at all.

After uninstalling KIS speed didnt changed. Then deleted some cookies and cleaned os with ccleaner, speed in IE became on average about 75 mbits but interrupting about once per gigabyte uploaded. Other browsers speed is  unchanged.

So ATM IE = 75 mbit, chrome = 5 mbit, opera = 4 mbit, firefox = 12 mbit

Comment: If you configure Chrome. so it sends a different user agent, does it still download at these lower speeds?

Comment: @Ramhound yeah, same 3.5-3.7 mbits for ie11/firefox 42/default user agent strings

Comment: @Ramhound https://www.youtube.com/html5 says 'using html5 if possible' in every browser, yes

Comment: @Ramhound Question is about uploading video on youtube servers, not about playing it tho. Checked every browser, if I press right click on a video, last menu is 'about html5 player'.

Comment: I glazed over that fact.  Disregard my comments then.

Comment: Is you hard drive cluttered? This is also a factor while uploading. The best way to get great uploads is to have your uploads on a drive that has very few items on it. Having a cluttered drive will cause the data to be slower and an overall slow processing speed. That covers the overall speed as for the Browsers some have more Threading then others.

Comment: @NetworkKingPin tried uploading file from ssd that is 38% free, speed is same (12 mbit in firefox, 5 in chrome). Ill try to defragment my hard drive, maybe it will help. Will creating 100 GB partition on almost full 2TB drive help against cluttering?

Comment: It will not really make a difference as the whole drive is still working so it would be the same you could always test it if you want. I find this post very interesting. Going to do some research on this. Also what format do you upload the videos in? Do you compress them first?

Comment: Is your drive speed the limiting factor? I might not be your internet, but your dive might be failing. Can you check upload speed to other websites?

Comment: @JCTechie I tried uploading from different hard drives including an ssd, speed doesn't changes. Uploading file from ssd to mega.co.nz: firefox: 14 mbit, chrome: 6-ish, opera 5-6, IE - 15-17 mbits

Comment: Related http://superuser.com/questions/1083759/http-upload-performance-in-various-browsers-and-oss